# this transaction spends an input which is unconfirmed ~ 2 hours now

Tags: transactions

So i've been waiting 2 hours for this;
https://blockchain.info/tx/df1d61ba4248d502bec5ff542c19eee6cbe7c88d607af89ff5ab485ec1f3800f?currency=BTC

I bought something with blockchain wallet via a site that had bitpay and when i sent it said success but its not confirming its been 2 hours now? i

Comment: It's normal for a transaction with an unconfirmed input to take a very long time to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [it was included in block #441,569](https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/df1d61ba4248d502bec5ff542c19eee6cbe7c88d607af89ff5ab485ec1f3800f) and currently has 126 confirmations.